# Django select_related user_permissions

Tags: python, django

How can I use select_related on user_permissions? I tried

```
select_related('user,' 'user__user_permission')
```

but it looks like it still is looking in database when I use `self.has_perm('forums.can_moderate')` on the user object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select_related` method only works on many_to_one or one_to_one relations (with which there can only be one target). So to begin with, you cannot use `select_related` to preload several permissions. For this, you should look at `prefetch_related` instead.

You have two options:

- Either you actually need to know all (or most) permissions, and you use `prefetch_related`.
- Or you only need to check a few permissions and you filter on them manually.

Either way, the `has_perm` method will not use prefetched data. You want to check the permission objects you load manually. Using the first approach:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.prefetch_related('user__user_permissions')
for obj in qs:
   for permission in obj.user.user_permissions.all():
       print('On object %d, permission %s' % (obj.pk, permission.codename))
```

Using the second approach:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(user__user_permissions__codename='can_moderate')
for obj in qs:
    print('Object %s has a user with permission can_moderate' % obj.pk)
```

Just to be sure: this does not involve object-based permissions. It merely filters objects associated to a user that has the generic can_moderate permission (on all objects). For object-based permissions, you need a third party module, such as django-guardian.